# alignment in recommendation letter in hardcopy

Tags: recommendation-letter

I have taken letter of recommendation from my referee with signature on letter head but the email and phone are not aligned with the rest of the document. Would the Australian university consider it ambigous and will contact my referee for it? I am applying for a highly competetive scholarship in australia. Can this appear as forgery case?

The below text will tell you how it looks on LOR and there  is change in left side alignment.

```
                    Dr. XYZ
```

Email:                             phone: 22

I want to recommend...                 are

Comment: It's going to be fine.  It is not at all unusual for information that's printed on a letterhead to be restated in slightly different format in an email signature.

Answer (score 5):

Nobody cares about minor formatting inconsistencies in a letter of recommendation.  There is no worldwide standardization of formatting and writers write in all sorts of idiosyncratic ways.  Moreover, since the readers will be reading lots of these in quick succession, it is unlikely they will even notice.

If by some remote chance they do happen to notice, and if by some even more remote chance they think it indicates potential forgery (and I see no reason why they should), then they will simply contact your referee and your referee will confirm that the letter is genuine, and everything will be fine.  This isn't something you need to worry about.  It certainly isn't worth spending any time or effort trying to correct the formatting, nor is it worth asking the referee to fix it.

Comment: You only need to worry about it if, indeed, you forged the letter and the odd alignment is a result of the forgery!

Comment: I am only worried because my referee is very busy, and doesn't reply to emails, until I go myself and contact him that an email is needed to be sent from his email address. The university may not inform me that they are going to contact my referee. And what would be the consequences of silence from my referee in such a case?

Comment: @anonymous090: I would hope that the letter recipients would make a concerted effort to contact the letter writer (more than a single email) before assuming the letter is fake and treating the application negatively.  I would also hope that a non-automated email saying something like "Possibly fake letter of recommendation sent in your name" would get your referee's attention, no matter how busy he is.  If he really didn't respond at all, I'm not sure what would happen - I doubt this situation is common enough for there to be a standard protocol for it.